# Trigger in mysql updating in another database

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

is there something wrong with this trigger ? It suppose to update a datefield on a table in another database. Can anyone give me a hand ? thanks

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS depoisDeInserir_invoice;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER depoisDeInserir_invoice AFTER INSERT ON pag_invoice 
FOR EACH ROW   

BEGIN
    DECLARE trial datetime;         

    SET trial = (select dataTrial
                 from networkcen_1.companyproductuser 
                 where (CompanyKey = NEW.companyKey) 
                 and (ProductKey = NEW.productKey)
                 and (UserKey = NEW.productKey));

    IF (trial < CURDATE()) THEN    
        UPDATE networkcen_1.companyproductuser 
        SET dataVencimento = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL NEW.dias DAY)  
        where (CompanyKey = NEW.companyKey)  
        and (ProductKey = NEW.productKey)  
        and (UserKey = NEW.productKey);
    ELSE
        UPDATE networkcen_1.companyproductuser  
        SET dataVencimento = DATE_ADD(trial,INTERVAL NEW.dias DAY)  
        where (CompanyKey = NEW.companyKey)  
        and (ProductKey = NEW.productKey)  
        and (UserKey = NEW.productKey);
    END IF;
END;

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you pls share the specific error message or unexpected behaviour you encounter?

Comment: dont display any error